# MathJax: Hide page until all math formulas are typesetted

Tags: javascript, mathjax

A [typical page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2) with numerous math formulas is usually typesetted by MathJax in "slow motion": You are shown the LaTeX codes in gray first, before the formulas are converted one by one. Is it possible to configure MathJax / use Javascript in such a way that this typesetting process is hidden, so that nothing is shown (meaning you only see a blank page) until all formulas are ready?

Comment: Do you want to hide the the TeX code or the entire content (math and non-math)?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Sorry I meant we are supposed to be shown a blank page until all formulas are rendered. Please see the edit.

Comment: I'm also interested in this issue, as it affects some markdown editors that subcontract math rendering to html+mathjax. https://github.com/retext-project/retext/issues/540

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on how fancy you want to be, but the quick and dirty way is to hide everything and use the MathJax queue to turn things visible.

1) make your main element `visibility:hidden` (don't use `display:none`, this can interfere with MathJax)

2) Then, after the call to `MathJax.js`, add a script to remove `hidden` after the initial bunch of elements in the MathJax queue have been cleared (i.e., the initial typesetting is done). Something like this

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(
   function () {
     document.getElementById('MainID').style.visibility = "";
}
```

);

should do the trick -- see http://jsfiddle.net/26rvZ/

I hope this gets you started.